# RaycastHit returns terrain, i want gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have scene with terrain and ball. Ball is moving. I want to detech slice on it. How can I do this?
I have such сode:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Vector3 pos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                pos.y = 0.2f;
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
                RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    timeToShoot = true;
                }
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                //drag
                if (timeToShoot)
                {
                    update = false;
                    timeToShoot = false;
                    shoot(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition * 5);
                }
            }
        }
```

And in log I can see only "Terrain".
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a raycast using a layermask. If you expose the variable as a public member variable in your MonoBehavior you can specify in the inspector which layers are a part of the layer mask.

```
public LayerMask layerMask;
```

Then, pass it into your raycast like so

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
{
    timeToShoot = true;
}
```

You may want to read up on [layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) if they are unfamiliar to you.